# Java Whirlpool hashing

Tags: java, whirlpool

I found myself in the need to hash something in Java and as I don't understand hashing I'm here.

I already found that there's no simple method for it.

So my question: **how is whirlpool hashing done in Java?**

EDIT: I was suggested GNU Whirlpool, but I can't get it to work

```
            Whirlpool wp = new Whirlpool();

            String s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
            byte[] b = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            wp.update(b, 0, s.length());
            byte[] r = wp.digest();

            String str = new String(r,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(str);
```

And the output is:
`<?R??XF
????n?g?Tl??H?po??????? m?
5?F ??
y?QhTM?|?I???`
Am I missing something? Or did I not understand how it works?

Solve: It seems the `digest` method outputs **raw** byte data. I converted it to HEX format using a method from [Apache common codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library.

Comment: Why not use one of the standard crypto libraries rather than trying to implement your own?

Comment: Standard libraries? I'd be happy to use them. Can I get a name which I could use?

Comment: `MessageDigest` has most of the crypto tools built into Java.

Comment: Second hit on Google: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch26_01.htm

Comment: Why do need whirlpool hashing specifically? Will any reasonable hash alg work for your needs, or is there a specific requirement for whirlpool?

Comment: The program will connect to my MySQL database for game server, which uses the Whirlpool hash. So if I need to check if the password is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GNU Whirlpool](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-crypto/manual/api/gnu/crypto/hash/Whirlpool.html). This is a java implementation of Whirlpool from GNU.

Comment: Could I get an example of it?

Comment: Is there any possible way of getting a code example of this used in a simple console Java application. I think that it would be good to see it in use. Is there something that has to be imported or is it already built into Java?